# How to deploy symfony2 using git

Tags: git, symfony

Ok, I did search about this and I have found several blogs but none of these work for me.  I want to use plain Git (no capistrano, capifony please).

I have symfony 2.5 and my remote server has linux red hat.

This is my first time using symfony and git, and ssh, so you can imagine what am going through, and I have been following several blogs I found.

My struggle is I cannot find a detailed explanationon how and where to create git project on my remote server, and what to do with symfony 'web' as opposed to remote 'public_html' folder.

I have followed post deployment steps here as well but I always get either 403 or 404. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html

Comment: Why don't you want Capifony?

Comment: I am hopelessly leaning into Capifony now.  Does it matter where I initialise git repo in remote server? and do I need to keep Symfony's folder structure?

Comment: If by remote server you mean the server that will host the application, then you shouldn't set up the git repository there. One does not **deploy** using git. Regarding public_html: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Create a git repository on Github or Bitbucket or you can you gitolite3 or Gitlab what you want to create a Git repo. Then create your repository and ignore all folder that could change.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony.gitignore

Here is an example what you should ignore. Then checkout that repository on your server. So now you have different possibilities.

1. Go to your server and run that command manually.
2. Create a script with the complete command and execute that script over SSH.
3. Use Ansible its very cool
4. Use jenkins what do the work for you and run commands on your server.

So its not really complicated you have to find the best way on your own and find a workflow you're happy with. And you should really take a look at capifony and unterstand the concept and why not using it? ;) its working especially when you are new.

Comment: I finally used Bitbucket and Capifony.  I was able to deploy the project but I am getting this :

~~    command finished in 70ms
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/operations/upload.rb:176:in `initialize': expected a file to upload (ArgumentError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:98:in `new'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:98:in `upload'...~~